# flutter navigator pushNamed wrong screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

i have 4 screen in order
and i created a button with a navigator pushNamed
when i press the button to navigate to the second page it"s go to the fourth page and

```
   return AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance, color: Colors.black),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyProfile.screenRoute);
        },
      ),
      title: Text(
        '',
      ),
      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      actions: [
        IconButton(
            onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.web_sharp, color: Colors.black)),
      ],
    );
```

when i click the iconbutton it"s navigate to another screen
this is my screen route

```
 routes: {
    // "home": (context) => Home(),
    "login": (context) => AuthScreen(),
    // "register": (context) => RegisterScreen(),
    "scooter": (context) => Scooter(),
    // "profile": (context) => MyProfile(),
    "map": (context) => Map(),
    Home.screenRoute: (context) => Home(),
    RegisterScreen.screenRoute: (context) => RegisterScreen(),
    MyProfile.screenRoute: (context) => MyProfile(),
    VisiterScreen.screenRoute: (context) => VisiterScreen(),
    UnivMap.screenRoute: (context) => UnivMap(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `screenRoute` value. Probably you forgot to change to myProfile path.

Comment: i add the screen route above

Answer (score 0):

I think your routes are duplicate, Check your screen path and try again